# PHP and JQuery Post communication errors

Tags: php, jquery

Ok, so i tried multiple of solutions but nothing seems to work for me, (or i'm just too stupid to get it).

I have such jquery code:

**Jquery:**

```
var current_id = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = {"id" : current_id};
$.post("popup.php" , {"id" : $(this).attr("id")}, function(msg) { alert(msg);} );
```

I know few lines are useless here but i tried all options,

**PHP:**

```
$tmp = $_POST['id'];
if($tmp == "kontakt"){
echo '<p>UDANE PRZESŁANIE</p>';}
else{
echo '<p>NIEUDANE PRZESŁANIE</p>';
}
```

When i click on id=kontakt php returns error :

```
 Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\***\popup.php on line 2
```

but alert sends back

```
<p>UDANE PRZESŁANIE</p>
```

Edit:

Ok, Maybe i haven't make my question clear. I don't care if php error is shown or not, I just want to know why it shows up in the first place.

Comment: What is `this` in your JavaScript Snipplet?

Comment: notice !=error so it actually still works.

Comment: I wonder why do you first assign a dataString, but then essentially throw it away - and calculate the data again? Why is `{"id": $(this).attr("id")}` code used twice?

Comment: @raina77ow: I think these are relicts from what the asker has tried...

Comment: But why try this instead of just logging the current_id value, I wonder? With `console.log(current_id)` or something like that. )

Comment: @Lukx `this` is $("img:[id!=home][class!=logo]")

Comment: `console.log(current_id)` and `console.log(dataString)` give back correct responses for example `kontakt` and `id: "kontakt"`

Comment: The post data is sending fine, that's why it's running the true if statement, the problem is only a php error. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a PHP warning - it's basically saying that $_POST has no index called 'id'.

You can get rid of it in several ways...

1. A shorted version of Austin Allover's answer:

   if(!isset($_POST['id')) $tmp = '';
2. Turn of warnings in your script or your php config file, see:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (Look for E_WARNING)
3. You might also want try $.post("popup.php" , {"id" : "BLAHBLAHBLAH"}, function(msg) { alert(msg);} ); - just in case $(this).attr("id") doesn't contain anything...

Answer (score 0):

Declare $tmp var this way:

```
$tmp = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : "";
```

Or ...

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) { $tmp = $_POST['id']; } else { $tmp = ""; }
```

If you don't understand what this code does...

if post id is set, then declare $tmp as the post id, else set $tmp as "". This will take away the PHP notice.

Comment: Ok, I got rid of the error but the echo still returns `$tmp=""`  i don't know why the `$_POST['id']` isn't working